# Join table with Sum(column) group by column in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have two tables one is 'emp' and other is overtime.
when i am joining those tables then overtime column is not getting correct value where overtime is null.
i am trying it

```
select e.emp_code,sum(o.overttime) 
from emp e,overtime o
group by e.emp_code,o.emp_code'
```

Comment: use nvl function  `sum(nvl(o.overtime,0))`

Comment: I have already tried but problem not solved.

Comment: what's the join condition?

Comment: I am also tried
'select (e.emp_code),nvl(sum(o.ot),0) from emp e,ovtime o
where o.emp_code=e.emp_code
group by e.emp_code,o.emp_code order by e.emp_code'

Comment: in upper query 'e.emp_code' not fully fetch data its showing only those record where o.overtime is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a join condition. and you should use `LEFT JOIN` as not every employee has records in the `OVERTIME` table.

Use the following query:

```
SELECT E.EMP_CODE,
       COALESCE(SUM(O.OVERTTIME),0) AS OVERTIME
  FROM EMP        E
  LEFT JOIN OVERTIME   O
ON E.EMP_CODE = O.EMP_CODE
 GROUP BY E.EMP_CODE
```